# Tomcat 8.0 Rewrite Valve

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to use the RewriteValve in Tomcat 8.0 http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html

In $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml, I added

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

right below the Host tag

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

Created a `rewrite.config` in the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf` directory with the following

```
RewriteRule ^/abc /myapp
```

where `http:/host:port/myapp` is a working webapp.

So now when I go to `http://host:port/abc` I expect to be redirected to `http://host:port/myapp` but I get a 404 `the requested resource is not available` instead.

It doesn't look like it is even reading my rewrite.config file. The access log in the logs directory just reports the `"GET /abc HTTP/1.1" 404 1000` with no further details.

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation, if you configure the rewrite valve in server.xml, you have to put the rewrite.config file in the "Host configuration folder".

The host folder is

```
$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/[host name]
```

or in your instance

```
$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost.
```

Comment: Fantastic.  The rewrite.config, placed anywhere else, did nothing.  Thanks!